# In what way is the "IF object_ID" clause used rather than creating a table from scratch? Does this save time when creating queries

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

One of our team members recently joined our group in a business analytics course and contest. He explains that he uses the above IF clause to delete and create temporary tables and this is easier for him than others. Can anyone explain what this fetches and how to decide many tables we would need to drop and create using this clause? Here is an example of his query:

```sql
IF object_ID('tempdb.dbo.#EricTest') is not null DROP TABLE #EricTest
IF object_ID('tempdb.dbo.#EricTest2') is not null DROP TABLE #EricTest2
SELECT DISTINCT xxxxxxxxxxx
INTO #EricTest
WHERE xxxxx
GROUP BY xxxxx

SELECT xxxxxx
INTO #EricTest2
FROM #EricTest, xxxxxx
GROUP BY xxxxxx
```

I am just curious how Eric would determine how many temporary views he would create dependent on the ask and any similar methods to this query method. My professor and class was not able to determine a solution or answer and would love some insight and explanation regarding the above query and why it works and what exactly it accomplishes.

Answer (score 1):

I do things like this in the interest of *idempotency*. Which is a fancy way of saying that if I run the same script multiple times, I should get the same result. Without those `drop table` statements, the second (and subsequent) runs of the script will throw an error saying "table already exists". At which point you'd be tempted to just put an unqualified `drop table` at the top of the script. But then the *first* run of the script will error out saying that the table doesn't exist!

This is a fairly pragmatic approach. I will note that in more recent versions (SQL 2016+ IIRC), there is `drop table if exists` syntax available that makes this sort of thing a) more straightforward b) less error prone (on more than one occasion I was testing existence for one table and trying to drop another. oops!) and c) easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

The `OBJECT_ID()` [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) returns, well, an object ID -- a small integer -- that is a unique key for the table object (or view, or procedure, or any other object type) named by its parameter. If that object does not already exist, then `OBJECT_ID()` returns `NULL`.

The idiom `IF OBJECT_ID('something') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [something]`, therefore, will execute `DROP TABLE` only when the `something` already exists.  If it doesn't already exist, it won't execute the `DROP TABLE`.

`DROP TABLE [something]` would generate an error if you tried to execute it when `something` doesn't exist. Therefore, using this idiom is a way to prevent that error.

At the final abstraction, this idiom makes sure the table doesn't exist before you create it.  Example B at the [linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation page shows this exact idiom being used.

I'm really not sure what you're asking by "how many temporary views he would create". The idiom would be used once per temporary table that the transaction intends to make use of.

*Frankly, testing for the existence of temporary tables seems like a waste of time to me.*